# Is my desktop app in scope for PCI certification?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, credit-card, pci-dss, pci-compliance

I have a payment processing client that runs exclusively on the desktop.  The operator enters payment data and clicks a button and my app sends the data off to a payment gateway via a secure channel.  My app never stores sensitive payment data, although it does encrypts and saves the merchant's gateway login info.

Am I in scope?  If I am, why are web browsers out of scope when the perform the exact same function in the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app handles card numbers and is involved in the authorisation and/or settlement of card transactions. If you are providing it as off the shelf software it is in scope for PA-DSS.

The organisation that installs your app and runs it in their environment is in scope for PCI-DSS.

Answer (score 3):

If the operator keys in a credit card card number then yes; your software both accepts & transmits cardholder data so it, the machine running it & any network(s) its attached to are all in scope of PCI and so must be compliant.

> **Q: [To whom does PCI apply](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-faqs-2/#2)?**
>   **A:** PCI
>   applies to ALL organizations or
>   merchants, regardless of size or
>   number of transactions, that **accepts**,
>   **transmits** or stores any cardholder
>   data. Said another way, if any
>   customer of that organization ever
>   pays the merchant directly using a
>   credit card or debit card, then the
>   PCI DSS requirements apply

Browsers are not in scope only when the person using one to enter card details is the *owner* of the card & not a 3rd party merchant. PCI only applies to merchants & other processing entities, not the customers of the issuing card schemes.

Comment: So what about the case where the operator places an order on behalf of the customer using a web browser? Many customers use their eCommerce system for phone orders.

Comment: As I see it the operator is employed by a merchant, the merchant has PCI obligations to the card issuers & since the operator is accepting card data it all falls under PCI scope. Take look @ http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2922/why-doesnt-the-clients-web-browser-need-to-be-pci-compliant

Comment: I'm still left scratching my head here.  I think I should have asked wether my application is in scope for PA-DSS certification. I've been told by certifiers that I do, but the more I think about it, I don't.